# Lenovo Windows 8 laptop always has "limited" wifi connection

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, home-networking

I have a Lenovo G585 laptop, running Windows 8.1, with an Atheros wireless card.  I am *always* having wireless connectivity issues with it:  it always shows up as a "limited" connection.  Even if it appears to be connected "normally," the internet soon slows down to a crawl:  I can type an address in a browser bar, and the computer sits there for a few seconds before even trying anything...and then, I often see messages like "resolving address" in the browser status bar before the webpage *finally* comes up, if at all.  We have multiple other devices (laptops, cell phones, Roku, etc) connected to the network, both wired and wirelessly, and they all connect/function just fine.

Here are all the things I tried, and hopefully additional clues for anyone interested in resolving this:

1. Wi-fi connection properties (passwords, MAC filter, etc.) were double-checked...also did some router resets, to be sure.
2. Scanned for viruses AND malware on the laptop...nothing (this computer was used infrequently until recently).
3. Ensured laptop OS was up-to-date (Windows Update).
4. Reset laptop's wireless adapter and wi-fi connection in various ways (disable/enable in Adapter Settings, ipconfig release/renew, etc.)
5. Tried to update the wireless card device driver via the "Update Driver" button in properties...it told me I already had the best driver.  Later on, also uninstalled the wireless card/adapter and forced Windows to do a plug-and-play reinstall.  I think I even tried "rolling back" the driver once (to a previous version).
6. Forced laptop to "forget" my wireless network configurations and re-entered them.
7. I tested connections with and without my third-party firewall (Windows' firewall is off)...no difference.
8. To me, here's the most significant piece of evidence:  thinking that there might be a hardware problem with the internal wireless card, I bought a USB wi-fi adapter, disabled the internal card, and properly installed the USB wi-fi adapter before attempting to use it...*the USB wi-fi adapter behaved exactly like the internal card did:  connection always was "limited" or slow, etc.*

From my research, I found the suggestion to ping my router.  On *occasion*, I get ping times of 4-6ms, but more often than not, I get average ping times of 448ms or such (longest 1197ms)...sometimes, I'll even get total packet loss (the ping requests "time out").  I read that ping times this long are notable and indicate connectivity issues, but at this point I'm not sure where the issue lies.

I think that's just about everything I can recall, and I'm about to pull my hair out.  Is there anything else left to try?  Did I miss something, or is Windows 8 *really* this bad?

Thanks!